# Redundant meta in logo?

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, logo

Did I end up on the Stack Overflow meta for Stack Overflow meta, or is there something wrong with the logo?

[image]

Present on both Firefox and Chromium.

Comment: Yes I know, -1 not enough freehand circles. I'm lazy.

Comment: I was about to post the same question, but titled it "Is Meta getting too meta?" :)

Comment: You can't get enough meta! Now SO has grown to massive proportions, we need a meta to discuss the issues in meta

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I messed up an if statement :) Fix rolling out right now, will mark this [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) when it finishes building.

Comment: `if (developer.acknowledgesFault && developer.fixesBug) {developer.thank() }`

Comment: `if (carpetsmoker->isOnline()) { echo 'meta'; }`